How can I improve my "design-choice" question?
My question recently got closed due to needing to be more focused,so I want to ask exactly what I should improve upon. In my view, I have put enough detail into the question, and described the problem I am looking to solve.
I have also described what I am thinking of to solve the problem (dynamically changing the on_message handler) but am failing. Please help me improve the question. Thanks!

"In my view, I have put enough detail into the question," - I read it 3 times, and still have no idea what you are trying to accomplish with that auth "command", this kind of flag and the websockets message handler. But the biggest flaw in that question is the question "What design should I choose for this functionality?" - IMHO this gives us zero information about where your actual problem is and what kind of help you need. Maybe you can start by editing a more specific and detailed example into your question how the auth functionalityl should work from a user's persepective?
